# German freelancer working for a UK company, what is needed?

Tags: legal, uk, germany

I'm living in Germany and registered as a *Freiberufler* and working (directly) for a couple of companies in here.

Now I got an offer for a contract with a UK based company, do I need any extra paperwork?

Comment: Extra paperwork for *what* exactly? For being foreign to the UK company? For being a German? For depositing money? What do you have already, and what do the contracts stipulate? Do they include everything you need to get paid, and report your income as required?

Comment: For being registered in Germany and working for a UK company. I have all I need for working for a German company as a *Freiberufler*. I would be working as a freelancer for that company too.

Comment: @CanadianLuke see my comment, hope that helps enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on many things...

- are you working in the UK or Germany?
- are you working directly for the client or via an agency

If you are working via an Agency, then the picture gets very cloudy, as most will not deal with an overseas company.  But as you do not mention an agency, I'm assuming this doesn't apply?

If you are working directly for the UK client, from your location in Germany, then all that is necessary is for your company to invoice the client... and no UK tax or employment regulations apply.

If you are working directly for the UK client, from a UK location, then (in effect) your German company is establishing a UK branch, and is [potentially subject to UK tax](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/manuals/ctmanual/ctm93250.htm) and also you would be subject to UK employment legislation (in particular the [infamous IR35 may be applicable](https://www.gov.uk/ir35-find-out-if-it-applies)).

I recommend proper professional advice, as taking the wrong option could be expensive in the long run!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm working in Germany directly for the client. So I guess I don't need to change anything and invoice them normally.

Comment: In that case, then yes.  I have done the reverse (working for a German client, from the UK) and just submitted an invoice... Feel free to upvote/accept the answer :)